# assigning same values in a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of 20 values for every user in a dictionary

```
weights = {1:[0.16, 0.16, 0, 0.32, ...], 2:[0, 0.32, 0, 0.16, ...]}  # till user id 213
```

Every index in the list belongs to a certain category, i.e, 0.16, 0 from first index of user 1 and 2 respectively belong to the same category.
Given that I have an empty list for all categories. I require the weight of one category to be repeated as many time as the user id exists

```
user id  category A
1        0.16
1        0.16
...
1        0.16
2        0
2        0
...
3        0.32
...
```

This is the kind of output I would like, I would like to repeat the same for all categories

Comment: I'm not really following. *"Given that I have an empty list for all categories"* - Where is that empty list? *"as many time as the user id exists"* - It's a dict, so each user ID exists only once, no? Could you make a [mre] including some example input and full expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `items()` method of the dictionary.

```py
for (user_id, categories) in weights.items():
    for item in categories:
        print(user_id, item)
```

However, I think the situation you have is a bit more complex than you described. It would help to have the full input rather than just some of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import pandas as pd
 max_len=max([len(value) for key,value in weights.items() ])
 weights = {1:[0.16, 0.16, 0, 0.32], 2:[0, 0.32, 0, 0.16],3:[3,4,2,1]}
 weights_dataframe=pd.DataFrame()
 for x in range(max_len):
   if x==0:
       weights_dict={key:[weights[key][0] for x in weights[key]] for key in weights}
       weights_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(weights_dict).melt()
   else:
       weights_dict={key:[weights[key][x]] for key in weights}
       weights_dict=pd.DataFrame(weights_dict).melt()
       weights_dataframe=pd.merge(weights_dataframe,weights_dict,left_on='variable',right_on='variable')
 weights_dataframe.columns=['user_id','A','B','C','D']
 print(weights_dataframe)
```

[image]

Explanation: create an empty dataframe weights_dataframe. for length of categories, loop & for 1st categories, assign the dictionary values to weights_dataframe after melting else merge with weights_dataframe